# Sentence construction in past tense

Tags: sentence-construction

a) I went to his home and find/found he was not there.

b) I went to his house in the morning, I find/found him lying on ground.

C) I was driving yesterday, and about to give up my search, I find that house.

If sentence is in past tense, then can we use simple form of Verb ?

Comment: Why mix in the present tense? Just use past tense.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not idiomatic in British or American English. The events took place in the past; consequently, the normal tense used is the past tense for **ALL** the verbs (ignoring situations calling for past perfect or past conditionals).

There is something called "the historical present," where the present tense is used to describe past events. But when that relatively rare rhetorical device is used, it is used **consistently.**

In short, do not switch tenses for events that occur in the same narrative period

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as what Jeff Morrow said, use past tense.

Some tidying up is suggested.

The original b) has a comma splice problem.
The original c), further, has an extra comma after 'yesterday'.

My suggestions are shown below:

b) I went to his house in the morning 'and' found him lying on the ground.

or

b) I went to his house in the morning, 'and' I found him lying on the ground.

c) I was driving yesterday and about to give up my search; 'then', I found that house.